# How to make an custom base AMI to be used in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have this image:
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Y43P7X5?ref=cns_1clkPro
I want to use the nvidia drivers for machine learning purpose.

How can I use this image in my worker nodes with my eks cluster running on 1.15 version.

What will be the user data in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Amazon EKS-optimized accelerated AMI for this purpose.

The Amazon EKS-optimized accelerated AMI is built on top of the standard Amazon EKS-optimized Linux AMI, and is configured to serve as an optional image for Amazon EKS worker nodes to support GPU and Inferentia based workloads.

In addition to the standard Amazon EKS-optimized AMI configuration, the accelerated AMI includes the following:

```
NVIDIA drivers

The nvidia-container-runtime (as the default runtime)

AWS Neuron container runtime
```

The AMI IDs for the latest Amazon EKS-optimized accelerated AMI are shown in the following table. You can also retrieve the IDs with an AWS Systems Manager parameter using different tools. For more information, see Retrieving Amazon EKS-optimized AMI IDs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/gpu-ami.html

Comment: Any idea how we can get notified for latest AMI releases for EKS-Optimized AMIs?

Answer (score 2):

Since that image does not have necessary kubernetes binaries installed you may need to create a custom AMI from that image. Take look at [how to create a custom AMI for EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-custom-linux-ami/)

There is an option of self managed node while [lunching EKS worker nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html) and specify `NodeImageId`.

> **NodeImageId**: (Optional) If you are using your own custom AMI (instead
> of the Amazon EKS-optimized AMI), enter a worker node AMI ID for your
> Region. If you specify a value here, it overrides any values in the
> `NodeImageIdSSMParam` field.

Comment: I can take the base as my image (posted in link)

Comment: I have not tried this..so I can't fully confirm but give it a try